# jQuery clone div every time clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple form and with a button to clone my form when clicked. The problem is that when I click in button for the first time, it works correct, but for the next times it append many divs when clicked. Is there any way to copy one by one every time clicked?
here is my snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Add").click(function() {
        $(".formi").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
    });
});
```

```css
.formi {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
    <form class="formi">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
        <select name="cars">
            <option value="">one</option>
            <option value="">two</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">ok</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the first form instead of finding all in the DOM using `eq(0)` or find the recent one ,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Add").click(function(){
    $(".formi").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
//$(".formi:last").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
    });
});
```

```css
.formi{border:1px solid #000;width:50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
<form class="formi">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<select name="cars">
<option value="">one</option>
<option value="">two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

`$(".formi").clone().` clones all `.formi` element available on page. You need to only clone first `.formi`  element and not `.formi` which have been appended via template.

```
$(".Add").click(function(){
    var $formTemplate = $(".formi:first");
    $formTemplate.clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
});
```

Comment: You may want to `clone()` when the template is first initialized also, if you don't want the `input` values to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Use `first()` , The `first()` method returns the first element of the selected elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi").first().clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

  });
});
```

```css
.formi {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone only the first, using `.eq()` method, which reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Please try this:

```
$(".formi").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
```

References:

- [eq method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

  });
});
```

```css
.formi {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Add").click(function(){
  $(".formi").eq(0).clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");
    });
});
```

```css
.formi{border:1px solid #000;width:50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
<form class="formi">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<select name="cars">
<option value="">one</option>
<option value="">two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Add").click(function() {
    $(".formi:nth-child(1)").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

  });
});
```

```css
.formi {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
  <form class="formi">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
    <select name="cars">
      <option value="">one</option>
      <option value="">two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">ok</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

1. Add `:nth-child(1)` so that you will only clone the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Add").click(function(){
  $(".formi:last").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
<form class="formi">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<select name="cars">
<option value="">one</option>
<option value="">two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth-child(1)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Add").click(function(){
  $(".formi:nth-child(1)").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

    });
});
```

```css
.formi{border:1px solid #000;width:50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Add">Add+</span>
<div class="all">
<form class="formi">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<select name="cars">
<option value="">one</option>
<option value="">two</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Commented, where you are making mistake and what will be possible solution for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".Add").click(function() {
//Mistake : when you are clicking second time, you clone both the forms having class '.formi'
$(".formi").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last");

// $(".formi:nth-child(1)").clone().insertAfter(".formi:last"); : This one will work

  });
});
```